Numerical Solutions of DE with Symbolic Calculation
Dear Mathematica users,
I am trying to solve a system of differential equations (on Mathematica 14.0)
$0=\ddot{v}-\frac{M}{r^2}(\dot{v})^2$
$0=\ddot{r}-\frac{r^2 M'-rM+2M^2}{r^3}(\dot{v})^2+\frac{2M}{r^2}\dot{v}\dot{r}$
with the following condition.
$M(v)=\frac{M_0}{v_l^{1/3}}(v_l -v_0)^{1/3}$
Refering to Professor Dmitry Granin's mechanics example, I tried to mix symbolic and numerical calculation. For the first step, I tried to tidy up the equations by symbolic calculation like the following:

However, this cell isn't evaluated; the syntax notes that this is Incomplete expression: more input is needed. Is there a way to tackle this problem? Thank you.
(Edit)
Thanks so much to Bill, changing the variables' names avoided the errors mentioned above. The code now looks like the following, but still has errors like ReplaceAll and NDSolve. I will try to come back with a errorless code - feedbacks are always appreciated.
m = m0/vl^(1/3) (vl - v)^(1/3); vst1 = {v -> vt[t], vdot -> vt'[t], 
  vdotdot -> vt''[t], r -> rt[t]}; vst2 = {v -> vt[t], vdot -> vt'[t],
   r -> rt[t], rdot -> rt'[t], 
  rdotdot -> rt''[t]}; vstinv = {vt[t] -> v, vt'[t] -> vdot, 
  vt''[t] -> vdotdot, rt[t] -> r, rt'[t] -> rdot, 
  rt''[t] -> rdotdot}; eq1 = 
 0 == vdotdot - m/r^2 vdot^2 /. vst1; eq2 = 
 0 == rdotdot - (r^2 D[m, v] - r m + 2 m^2)/r^3 vdot^2 + 
    2 m/r^2 vdot rdot /. vst2;

v0 = 1; r0 = 8;
vv0 = 1; vr0 = 0;
tmax = 5;
vc = 1; M0 = 3;

Eqs = {eq1, eq2} /. {m0 -> M0, vl -> vc};
IniConds = {vt[0] == v0, vt'[0] == vv0, rt[0] = r0, rt'[0] == vr0};

Solution = 
 NDSolve[Join[Eqs, IniConds], {vt, rt}, {t, 0, tmax}, MaxSteps -> 1000]
vtt[t_] := vt[t] /. Solution[[1]]
rtt[t_] := rt[t] /. Solution[[1]]
Plot[vtt[t], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> {-100, 100}, PlotPoints -> 200]
Plot[rtt[t], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> {-100, 100}, 
 PlotPoints -> 200]


Please test this carefully. Is this exactly correct? m=m0/vl^(1/3)(vl-v)^(1/3); vst1={v->vt[t],vdot->vt'[t],vdotdot->vt''[t],r->rt[t]}; vst2={v->vt[t],vdot->vt'[t],r->rt[t],rdot->rt'[t],rdotdot->rt''[t]}; vstinv={vt[t]->v,vt'[t]->vdot,vt''[t]->vdotdot,rt[t]->r,rt'[t]->rdot,rt''[t]->rdotdot}; eq1=0==vdotdot-m/r^2 vdot^2/.vst1; eq2=0==rdotdot-(r^2 D[m,v]-r m+2 m^2)/r^3 vdot^2+2m/r^2 vdot rdot/.vst2; eq1/.vstinv eq2/.vstinv I am still not convinced that D[m,v] is exactly what you want.

Thanks. I guess the equations are accurate. I agree the D[m,v] could be ambigious, so I changed it to r^2*m0/(-3 vl*(1 - v/vl)^(2/3)). However, the error remains as $RecursionLimit...I'm still wondering where is the mistake.

I can't guess what your latest input was to get your recursion error. Can you edit your post or add a comment like I did showing exactly what you just gave Mathematica to get that error? There is a hidden cache in Mathematica that remembers all past assignments unless you have cleared that. Did you clear the cache or restart Mathematica and still got the recursion error? I am trying to duplicate exactly every step that you have taken so that I can try to show revised code that avoids the error.

Thank you for all the help. Your code worked magnificently; no more errors in symbolic calculation. The $RecursionLimit came from my mistake - maybe the Ctrl + ~ format isn't valid.However, since the original code was only a fragment of the whole code, it seems to have conflicts with my usage of NDSolve. I updated the numerical part of the code in the (Edit) part (yet unsolved). If you are interested, I'd love to hear your opinions.

IniConds = {...rt[0]=r0,...}; should be ``IniConds = {...rt[0]==r0,...};Your t ranges from 0 to 5. You havevt[0]==1. In eq2 you have -rt[t]^2/(1-vt[t])^(2/3)and at t==0 that is-rt[t]^2/ (1-1)^(2/3)and that isrt^2/0^(2/3)` and that is infinity. I can't guess what you need to do to get away from that infinity.
